# QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber() возвращает пустую строку

Tags: c++, qt, gui, serial

QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber() возвращает пустую строку, это не зависит от порта, подключал даже USB адаптеры RS-232, порт видит, а серийный номер не выдает.
Вот в этом слоте я пытаюсь вытащить серийный номер:

```
void PortBrowser::onPortChange()
{
int i;
if(comsCombo->currentIndex()>-1)
    i =comsCombo->currentIndex();
else
    i = 0;

QSerialPort currPort(comsList[i]);

bool opened =  currPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

const QString seriNum = comsList[i].serialNumber();

serNum->setText(seriNum);
manufact->setText(comsList[i].manufacturer());
QTextStream out(stdout);
out<<comsList[i].serialNumber();
currPort.close();
}
```

Comment: `Returns the serial number string of the serial port, if available; otherwise returns an empty string.` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html#serialNumber

Comment: @AlexanderChernin , а как сделать его доступным? Это возможно? Какой критерий доступности?

Comment: @DefusingDog, дык, посмотри исходники, откуда он берёт эти данные для твоей платформы...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, спасибо! Мне уже намекнули на то, что QT очень специфичным образом парсит серийный номер, скоро разберусь и залью ответ, коли получится.